# How can I get the process name from the foreground window on Windows using Java?

Tags: java, windows, process, window

I'm trying to get the name of the process from the foreground window, but I have some problems.

For example, if I open Mozilla firefox, it registers something like "www.google.com - Mozilla Firefox". In photoshop, it registers "filename.psd" + the zoom or the layer name you're working on.

I want to get the process name from the foreground window, I don't want it to detect every layer you're working on, etc, I just want it to get the process name (photoshop.exe or something like that)

For now, I'm using this to get the foreground window name and the ID of the process from that window:

```
public String getActiveProcess(){                   
    char[] buffer;
    HWND hwnd;
    String processName = ".... // ";
    IntByReference IdByRef = new IntByReference();

    //get window information
    buffer = new char[MAX_TITLE_LENGTH * 2];
    hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();

    //get process ID from window in foreground
    int processid = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, IdByRef);

    HANDLE processHandle = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(processid, true, MAX_TITLE_LENGTH);

    return processName;     
}
```

Comment: Processes don't have names. Why not ask about the real problem you are trying to solve, instead of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can call arbitrary Win32 functions, you can get the process ID using [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx), open a handle using [OpenProcess()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx), and get the executable name of the process using [GetModuleBaseName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Stucked with "GetProcessImageFileName()". I did the rest, but I'm stucked in that. Can you write some easy example of use?

Comment: Try GetModuleBaseName() instead.  If you still can't get it to work, add your new code to the end of your question and I'll see if I can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Code updated. I don`t know how to continue. I don't know how to use GetProcessImageFileName() or GetModuleBasename() in java